# extra 2.5" drive bay for laptop

Tags: laptop, ssd, frame

I'm going to buy a new laptop. It has 2 drive bays: Original HDD and blank.

I want to buy an SSD to use in the blank drive bay.

There is a frame that cover the HDD to avoid dust inside the laptop. My question is: **Do we need a frame to cover the SSD?**

Comment: What kind of laptop and SSD are you considering to buy? Right now it is difficult to answer your question since it is too general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I buy it for my Laptop, so it must be 2.5" SSD.
Anyway, I searched Google, and someone had the problem like me:
http://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/77120-how-install-mount-internal-laptop-hard-drive.html

My experience: if you plan to buy a new Laptop which has large screen > 15", you should make sure that it has 2 slots for hard drive. In general, there will be 1 empty slot, so you want to buy a SSD to put it in like me. I suggest you must contact the manufacture of your Laptop to buy the Hard Drive Caddy.

I plan to buy ASUS Laptop, so here is the place you can buy accessories from ASUS:
http://us.estore.asus.com/index.php?l=search_list&s[search]=Hard+Drive+Caddy&s[title]=Y&s[short_desc]=Y&s[full_desc]=Y&s[sku]=Y&s[match]=all&s[cid]=0